# How to show print media css on screen?

Tags: html, css

I have a different CSS that's applied when someone is printing (below is an example of how I'm doing it). But I'm wondering, I'd like to make a custom "Preview Print" (instead of the regular one in the browser) but I'm wondering if it's possible to somehow get it so that the print media css will be applied, because I'd like to show a preview on the screen of what they'll be printing on paper. Any ideas?

```
<html>
<body>

<style type="text/css">
body 
{
   font-size: 62.5%;
   background-color:black;
}
h1 
{
   color: red;
}
@media print 
{
body{
background-color:yellow;
}

  h1 {
  color: black;
   }
}
</style>

<h1>This is just a test</h1>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way would be to create a print.css style sheet that's normally included with `print` media specified.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="print" href="print.css" />
```

Then on your print preview screen, you could use the same print.css with `screen` media set:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="print.css" />
```

Comment: I guess the only problem is that I wouldn't be able to use inline print media then? I kind of wanted to as opposed to dealing with multiple css files :/

Answer (score 0):

I usually open a new window, write in my own generic html/body wrapper that uses the print stylesheet as the main stylesheet, the use JavaScript to copy the body from the opener to the window.