# how to get print preview (like image preview)

Tags: javascript, ajax, firefox

have tried window.print() and document..print() etc., but am not getting a preview.  I don't need a print dialog box displaying (ie., selecting a printer etc.); but need a preview.  Like Alt + F + V (print preview of browser).

Comment: you need to create alternate css layout for printing media

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9230336/how-to-show-print-media-css-on-screen

Comment: I have print.css and media=screen and i have a javascript to call print() method on click it fails.  my javascript is simple call to print() method window.print() document.iframe.print().  I think my css is good but need javascript help

Comment: see here http://jsbin.com/oyanac/2/edit

Comment: @eicto it works in chrome and i guess in IE as well.  But it directly shows me print dialog in firefox.  why firefox failing to show print preview.

Comment: because firefox has no print preview ?